# startActivity() not called immediately?

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm developing an Android app where the user can log in. For this every activity extends a `BaseActivity`. There, in the `onResume()` method, I check whether the user is logged in, and if not I start my `LoginActivity` by calling `startActivity()`.

This works with every activity, except one: let's call this `FailActivity`.

When `FailActivity` is resumed, its `onResume()` is correctly called, which in turn calls `super.onResume()`, and I get to `startActivity()`. But the intent is never executed. Instead `BaseActivity.onResume()` passes execution back to `FailActivity.onResume()`. This produces an error because the user is not logged in.

Here is the relevant code from `BaseActivity`:

```
@Override
protected void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    boolean wtf = false;

    if (!loggedIn) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(LoginActivity.EXTRA_NEXT_ACTIVITY, this.getClass().getName());
        startActivity(intent);
        wtf = true;
    }
    if (wtf)
        Log.wtf("wtf", "this should not happen");
}
```

I've tried calling `finish()` before and after `startActivity()`, and setting all kinds of flags in the intent, none of which do what I want.

How can I force execution of the login intent? Why does `startActivity()` seem to have no effect, and why only for this one activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `startActivity()` you start asynchronous a new Activity but the user will not be able to use the first Activity, since it will been replaced as fast as possible. But keep in mind that the user may see the title of the first Activity for a short period, the content itself should not be visible however we take here about 100ms or less.

If you want to skip the code in `onResume()` you can use a simple `return;`·

Comment: If I call `return` after `startActivity()` I return to `FailActivity.onresume()`, which is not what I want. Basically, is there a way to execute `startActivity()` synchonously?

Comment: No there is no way to execute Activities asynchronous. There is by the way the callback `onActivityResult()` to handle returning Activities or better the result of an Activity.

Comment: If I put `if (!loggedIn) return;` after `super.onResume()` in `FailActivity` everything works. Thanks!